# File Upload in PHP: GPX

Tags: php, xml, upload, gpx

Trying to upload a GPX(xml) file using PHP Form.

Form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_gpx.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000000" />
Upload  GPX File: <input name="file" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Send File" />
```

Script:

```
$allowedExts = array("gps","xml","gpx");
$fileName="rk".".gpx"; 
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/gpx") ||($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/xml"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 50000000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        if (file_exists("files/gpx/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "files/gpx/" .$fileName);
            echo "Stored in: " . "files/gpx/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];        
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "files/gpx/" .$fileName);
            echo "Stored in: " . "files/gpx/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
    }
} else { 
    echo "Invalid file";
}
```

When upload a xml file works fine, when upload a .gpx file it simply goes to "Invalid file" echo. Tried changing the "== "text/gpx")" to "== "application/gpx")" but same result. Any idea how to correctly upload a .GPX file? Would be helpful.

EDIT: As a temporary fix changed "($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/gpx")" to "($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/octet-stream")" and worked.

Comment: Did you check what is actually in `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` when you upload a `.gpx` file? A simple `echo $_FILES["file"]["type"]` will tell you

Comment: Checked just now, changed file type to "application/octet-stream" and worked perfectly.